# Notation about a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, linear-transformations

Let $E=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $F$ a linear subspace of $E$.
Then we have $E=F \oplus F^{\perp}$.

Is it clear (and correct) if one defines : $s:=Id|_{F}+\tilde s$ ?
(Where $\tilde s \in \mathcal{L}(F^\perp,F^\perp$)

To me that notation is quite ambiguous because I tend to understand it like this :

$$(Id|_{F}+\tilde s)(x)=Id|_{F}(x)+\tilde s(x).$$

That way of thinking is obviously false if the notation is correct since $Id|_{F}$ and $\tilde s$ are not defined on the same spaces. So one should read : $$(Id|_{F}+\tilde s)(x)=Id|_{F}(x_F)+\tilde s(x_{F^\perp}).$$

So :

1. Is the notation ok ?
2. If not, is there a better and simple notation ?

Reference (in french) at the beginning of the second page : [here](http://florian.bouguet.free.fr/doc/developpements/cartan_dieudonne.pdf)

Comment: Is $\;s\;$ a linear map? And then, *what* is $\;\tilde s\;$ ?? If you don't say, **of course** the notation is pretty ambiguous....also, you have the usual, standard inner product in $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ , right?

Comment: I do not fully understand what is $s$ since I do not fully understand the notation. I understood that $s \in \mathcal{L}(E,E)$. $\tilde s$ can be any linear map from $F^\perp$ to the same subspace. And yes, we have the standard inner product if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then there is no ambiguity at all: any $\;v\in\Bbb R^n\;$ is **uniquely** expressible as $\;v= f+\tilde f\;,\;\;f\in F\;,\;\;\tilde f\in F^\perp\;$ , so that

$$sv=\left(Id_F+\tilde s\right)(f+\tilde f)=Id_Ff+Id_F\tilde f+\tilde sf+\tilde s\tilde f=f+0+0+\tilde s\tilde f=f+\tilde s\tilde f$$

Comment: Note that there is some *extension by zero* going on in the background.

Comment: @b00nheT Who are you addressing? Because I've no idea what you meant nor what "extension by zero" could possibly mean.

Comment: I'm mainly addressing the OP. $Id_{F}$ is not defined on the whole of $E$ a priori. You are using $Id_F$ as the orthogonal projection onto $F$, which is well defined on $F^\bot$, and zero there. And similarly for $\tilde{s}$. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @b00nheT You're completely right and your point is completely correct and relevant. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your map splits as$$E\rightarrow F\oplus F^\bot\rightarrow F\oplus F^\bot\rightarrow E$$
$$x\mapsto (x_F,x_{F^\bot})\mapsto (x_F,\tilde {s}(x_{F^\bot}))\mapsto x_F+\tilde {s}(x_{F^\bot}),$$
and is indeed linear because projections are linear and composition of linear maps is linear.

In this way the map is unambiguously defined, but the notation is not very economical.

It might be helpful to provide a reference for your question.

Comment: Thank you. The reference is in french, I will add a link to it anyway. Do you have an idea of what could be a better notation for it ?

Comment: There is no problem in your notation, as long as you take the time to clarify what exactly is meant by it, so that the reader knows exactly what is going on. I personally see your notation as quite economical, but I would rather avoid writing the $Id|_F$ which is superfluous: just write
$$x\mapsto Pr_F(x)+\tilde{s}(Pr_{T^\bot}(x))$$